# How many are not divisible by

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How many numbers from $1$ to $1100$ are not divisible by any of $2, 5$, and
$11?$

Self attempt:
So $|2|=550$; $|5|=220$; $|11|=100$

Using inclusion-exclusion principle, would this be the right setup?
$1100=550+220+100 - 110(2 \cap 5 = 10) - 50 (2 \cap 11 = 22) - 10 (5 \cap 11 = 110)$
?

Comment: there are 2 corrections to be made here: 1) 20(5 intersection 11 = 55) and 2) You should add 10(2 intersection 5 intersection 11) on the RHS.

Comment: Atrocious notation... better use something like $S_5$ for the set of multiples of 5.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers divisible $2,5,11$ : $n(2)+n(5)+n(11)-n(2 \cap 5)-n(5 \cap 11)-n(11 \cap 2)+n(2 \cap 5 \cap 11) = 550 + 220 + 100 - 110 - 20 - 50 + 10 = 700.$

So numbers not divisible by $2,5,11$ :

$1100 - 700 = 400$

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese remainder theorem $\def\Z{\mathbf Z}\Z/110\Z\cong\Z/2\Z\times\Z5\Z\times\Z/11\Z$, and the number of its elements that have nonzero coefficients in each of the the three factors are is $(2-1)\times(5-1)\times(11-1)=40$. The range $1$ to $1100$ contains exactly $10$ representatives of each class modulo $110$, so your get $10\times40$.